LTSPICE output wrong DC voltages on this simple 2 capacitors in series
This is a very simple circuit with 2 identical capacitors in series and powered by a DC supply (1V) and also connected to ground as in the image. As you can see,  Vc2 is expected to be half of V1, which is 0.5V.  However, LTSpice comes with Vc2 = 0V no matter what.  Please help me what I did wrong? However,  when I changed V1 from DC source to a pulse source and LTSpice provides correct result.  Thanks!


You're just using the wrong command. .tran 1 finds a static solution, which is not useful in the case of anything with capacitors.
If you find a non-static solution using either .tran 1 startup or .tran 1 uic, you will get the expected result. Ignore all these other answers invoking things about capacitors not passing current, being non-ideal, etc. etc. Ideal or non-ideal, if you put 1V across two equally sized capacitors in series, you will eventually reach a state of 0.5V across each capacitor, full stop. LTSpice will correctly show that IF you ask it to.

The reason the OP is getting the result listed above is that node VC2 is floating (see the warning in the log file). Using your method, you might get the correct answer, but also have a floating node warning. Both model outputs are questionable.

Capacitors don’t pass DC current, there has to be a change in the voltage for there to be any current through the capacitors. When you switched to a pulse you gave it a change in voltage so some current did pass through the capacitors.
If you built a circuit like this with real capacitors you may get some current with a DC voltage because real capacitors aren’t perfect and can have a parasitic resistance which will pass DC, but you’re more likely to see that with large electrolytic capacitors than the type you would see used at 0.047uF.

Yes - that means: In practice,the voltages across two or more capacitors in series will be determined by the leakage resistors only (steady state condition).

Delete .OP and used .tran 1 UIC.


As you can see, Vc2 is expected to be half of V1

Why? You have not specified any constraints that would make it so. In fact, any combination of voltages across the two capacitors is valid as long as their series combination adds up to 1V. The top one could be 1000V, bottom one -999V.
And that's not even some theoretical thing either. If C1 and C2 have high dielectric absorption, and you have used them for other things very recently, then you connect them in the circuit you show (say 1.5V battery for V1), they may well rise to several hundred volts on their own. And their sum will still be 1.5V or whatever V1 is :)

You get a warning that node VC2 is floating but it still does the transient simulation without adding any parallel resistances (below):
The value of any parallel high capacitor resistance is only important for the long term voltages across the capacitors.  It does not affect the short-term transient response.


As others have mentioned, the problem is that you are using ideal capacitors who's impedance is infinite at DC. When you start doing math with infinities, things can go wrong.
Start of edit
You can verify this by checking the spice model log (hit control-L after running your model).

Note the warning that node VC2 is floating. This is because the voltage cannot be determined using your current analysis parameters.
End of edit
The resistance of a capacitor is something you usually don't find in the data sheets. It's big, but it's not infinity. If you want to see how the DC resistance changes the output of your model, right click on the the capacitors and set the equivalent parallel resistance to something big (say "1G" for 1 Giga-Ohm). You can make it visible in the model by hitting control then right clicking the capacitor and checking the "Vis." box (visible) on the spice line row. If you run the model again you should get the following:

As you can see, the voltage at node VC2 is now 0.5 V, where before it was 46 nano-volts.
Start of edit
If you check the log again, you'll see there are no warnings.
End of edit

Sorry, but this is incorrect. This is no different than just adding a 1GΩ resistor across each capacitor. Of course you get 0.5V, you just made a resistive voltage divider. Try changing one resistor to, say, 3GΩ. If what you are claiming were true, you would still get 0.5V. But you'll get either 0.75V or 0.25V depending on which parallel resistance you changed.
However, if you tell LTspice to find a non-static solution by using the correct simulation command switch (startup or uic), you get the correct result - with or without any parallel resistance.

@metacollin I agree that if you set the two parallel resistances to different values, you'll get different voltages for VC2. However, in the question the OP implied that the two capacitors are equal, which means that the parallel resistances are equal. Unless I'm mistaken, the only way to clear the floating node warning is to add parallel resistance to the capacitors.
